# Mapping a DTO to Entity with @Verion column-Spring Boot Hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, version-control, dto, optimistic-locking

I have a DTO which need to be mapped to Entity with a @Version column in DB, and then to do update.

Before mapping I get the Entity from database (I need it because of some validations and comparations) and then use the mapper.
So, the code is like this:

```
Entity fromDB = getEntity(eDto.getId());
Entity forUpdate = mapper.toEntity(fromDB, eDto);
```

Mapper:

```
Entity toEntity(@MappingTarget Entity e, EntityDto eDto);
```

In EntityDto I have few columns and Version also. But after getting the Entity from DB it is in PersistenceContext and the version can not be changed, so even if I use the wrong Version number, I never get the Optimistic Lock Failure exception.
Any suggestion how can I resolve this issue?

**UPDATE:**
(here is an example)

1. user1 get the entity with id 1 and version 1 on UI
2. user1 make some changes on entity
3. in the meantime some other user have changed and saved the object to DB (now version is 2)
4. user1 call updateEntity with version 1 and it comes to my method for update
5. I take the entity from DB  (and now the version is 2)
6. I map it to forUpdate (BUT HERE VERSION IS NOT MAPED because fromDB is in PersistenceContext and it is not allowed to change version)
7. the changes are made, and they should NOT be made because versions are not the same!

Comment: you should check hibernate entity types i.e. detached, managed, new etc. if you fetch an entity from the db, you need to update field and `@version` should not be set by the user

Comment: how to check version then? if dto version is different from entity version, it should not do the update

Comment: you shouldn't need to check if version has changed, hibernate takes care of that

Comment: I think you did not understand my question. Hibernate check the version of the entity taken from database, but I need to get the version from the dto entity, because that's the entity that I get from frontend and in the meantime the entity in database could have changed

Comment: @hamid I updated the question, so please check it again

Comment: `@Version` is more for when a record is read from db, updated, then written to the db. However, imagine before writing to the db, another process updates the record. So, hibernate complain as the version that is in the memory is no longer valid

Comment: i understand your use-case, however, this is not what @Version is used for. What you are looking for is `ETag`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how helpful this is for you, but I think [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) would be the perfect fit for your situation.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@UpdatableEntityView
@EntityView(Entity.class)
public interface EntityDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    Set<SubDto> getRoles();

    @EntityView(SubEntity.class)
    interface SubDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`EntityDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, EntityDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<EntityDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

With the [Spring WebMvc integration](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#entity-view-deserialization) you can even materialize the entity view like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/my-endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> updateCat(@RequestBody EntityDto dto) {
    myRepository.save(dto);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(dto.getId().toString());
}
```

It will be persisted/updated just as you would expect it!